# Bootstrap-Selectpicker: How to speed up fetching of data on huge records?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-selectpicker

**Situation:** When the page loads, it will automatically populate the dropdown box with 'employees'. (2,000+ records fetched as of now)

Then I have to select an employee over thousands of it from the records.

Everything works absolutely fine.

**Question:**
How am I going to increase its fetching speed if ever I have 10,000+ of data to be retrieved in the future?

Are there any better options for this?

I want to stick on searchable selects as possible. If not, please suggest a good one.

Here are my codes on CodeIgniter:
Controller:

```
public function employee()
{   
    $data["get_employee"] = $this->Home_model->get_query_array("SELECT employee_id, employee_name FROM Employee_List");

    $this->load->view('header_view');
    $this->load->view('employee_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer_view');
}
```

Model:

```
public function get_query_array($query_statement)
{ 
    $query = $this->db->query($query_statement);
    return $query->result();
}
```

View:

```
<label for="employee">Employee</label>
<select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="employee" id="employee">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    foreach($get_employee as $row)
    {
        $id = $row->employee_id;
        $name = $row->employee_name;
        echo "<option value='".$id."'>".$name."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Hey mate, for more than 50 records for select dropdrown, I suggest you to use ajax select dropdown.

Comment: Yes mate, ajax it is. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute this query for large data definitely your page will going slow.

 For this, i will prefer you go with ajax select PHP search dropdown. Here is a good example https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/  Please try with it. This will be very usefull for you. In this section , You will find your page is fast and its looking good as a feature in form or where you use this. 
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create dropdown of alphabets from A to Z then click hover of any character using ajax load the employees matching that character.In this way you can reduce the no. of employee loading at a time and it will reduce the fetch time from server because if you try to load all at once it will surely take time.